# Remove tweet regular expressions from string of text

Tags: regex, excel, vba, tweets

I have an excel sheet filled with tweets. There are several entries which contain @blah type of strings among other. I need to keep the rest of the text and remove the @blah part. For example: "@villos hey dude" needs to be transformed into : "hey dude". This is what i ve done so far.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim counter As Integer
Dim strIN As String
Dim newstring As String

For counter = 1 To 46
    Cells(counter, "E").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = strIN
    StripChars (strIN)
    newstring = StripChars(strIN)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = StripChars(strIN)
Next counter
End Sub

Function StripChars(strIN As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 With objRegex
 .Pattern = "^@?(\w){1,15}$"
.ignorecase = True
StripChars = .Replace(strIN, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```

Moreover there are also entries like this one: Ÿ³é‡ï¼Ÿã€€åˆã‚ã¦çŸ¥ã‚Šã¾ã—ãŸã€‚ shiftã—ãªãŒã‚‰ã‚¨ã‚¯ã‚¹ãƒ

I need them gone too! Ideas?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? You did not describe it. And a hint: replace `.Pattern = "^@?(\w){1,15}$"` with `.Pattern = "(^|\s)@\S+\s*"` and replace with `$1`, not `vbNullString`.

Comment: Currently, what this does is to delete the entire entry which includes @blah, while I need to keep the rest of the text after removing the "@blah"

Answer (score 0):

For every line in the spreadsheet run the following regex on it: `^(@.+?)\s+?(.*)$`

If the line matches the regex, the information you will be interested in will be in the second capturing group. (Usually zero indexed but position 0 will contain the entire match). The first capturing group will contain the twitter handle if you need that too.

[Regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/tG2vR4/1).

However, this will not match tweets that are not replies (starting with @). In this situation the only way to distinguish between regular tweets and the junk you are not interested in is to restrict the tweet to alphanumerics - but this may mean some tweets are missed if they contain any non-alphanumerical characters. The following regex will work if that is not an issue for you:
`^(?:(@.+?)\s+?)?([\w\t ]+)$`

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/tG2vR4/2).

Comment: Currently, what this does is to delete the entire entry which includes @blah, while I need to keep the rest of the text after removing the "@blah". I do not have any special knowledge on visual basic (i.e. I have no idea what is the capturing group that you mentioned), so I am really in a position to follow what you are saying. If you could explicitly tell me what I need to do..this would be great! Thanks!